# Do not open the app when a local notification is clicked in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

When I click on a local notification from the notification centre I want to prevent it from opening my application, i.e when the notification is clicked nothing should happen other than just clearing it. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Not possible, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***For sure Apple will reject such app.***

But below is what you can do if you want to do such thing, but this will open app.

In `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {`, have below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //home button press programmatically
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];

    //exit app when app is in background
    exit(0);
}
```

*In short, on opening app from push, kill the app.*

Comment: This what even I understood from reading many posts, that the app will be rejected. But still wanted to confirm it. Thanks

Comment: So if i want to open a specific view after clicking a notification how do i do that in didReceiveLocalNotification function? Please note i want to open a specific view and not a specific tab

Comment: @bash : do you still need help for going to another view?

Comment: No, Thanks. I did it myself

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is very old, but I found this while trying to figure out how to do this myself. I figured I'd update in case anyone else ran into it.

I was working on Project 21 Hacking With Swift when one of the challenges asks you to set a "Remind Me Later" option from a notification. Obviously, opening the app is useless in this scenario, so I tried to figure it out as well.

This is the way that I found is actually fairly simple. You only have to delete one piece of your code when registering your categories.

For example:

```
func registerCateories() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self  //  Any messages get sent back to us

    let show = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "show", title: "Tell me more", options: .foreground)
    let remindMeLater = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "remindMeLater", title: "Remind me later...")
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "alarm", actions: [show, remindMeLater], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])
}
```

Your two options to tap from the local notifications are `show` and `remindMeLater`. Note that `show` has `options: .forground`. This is what forces your app to open when clicked. Remove that (like in `remindMeLater`) and you solve your issue!

Later on in your code, you can call a different function based on the `response.actionIdentifier` in the `userNotificationCenter` function to make the tap actually do something.

Hope this helps!